# Efficient chunking timeseries in R

Tags: r, forex

I am working with a number of large timeseries currency pair pricing data in R. Files tend to be 100-300MB in size, and I will generally be working with 3 files at a time. I am looking for a (much) more efficient way of considering the TIME column of these data.

My data begins looking like :

```
  PAIR    TIME                    BID    ASK
1 USD/JPY 2012-01-02 00:00:00.307 77.023 77.055
2 USD/JPY 2012-01-02 00:00:00.493 77.030 77.049
3 USD/JPY 2012-01-02 00:00:05.003 77.030 77.050
4 USD/JPY 2012-01-02 00:00:05.005 77.023 77.056
5 USD/JPY 2012-01-02 00:00:05.006 77.024 77.056
6 USD/JPY 2012-01-02 00:00:06.008 77.023 77.056
...       ...                     ...    ...
```

R has no problem understanding the TIME column. For instance,

```
USDJPY$TIME[2] - USDJPY$TIME[1]
```

Gives output

```
Time difference of 0.1860001 secs
```

Data are already organized into files by month. Unfortunately this is also much too large. I would like to break down pricing data by 'trading week'

Forex trading occurs in continuous multi-day stretches, usually from Monday to Friday. Some trading holidays will suspend trading, and there will not be data on these days. The nature of trading scheduling is such that, if

```
USDJPY$TIME[t+1] - USDJPY$TIME[t]
```

... is greater than 12 hours, time t is the last time index for that week in USDJPY.

I have not found an acceptable way to break the data into trading weeks, by indices, or otherwise. All my attempts end up hanging. The USDJPY file contains ~1,900,000 rows.

One approach I tried :

```
for(i in 1:(length(USDJPY$TIME)-1)){
  USDJPY.diff <- c(USDJPY.diff, USDJPY$TIME[i+1]-USDJPY$TIME[i])
}
```

takes far too long (I quit before it could finish)

Comment: have you tried making an offset vector (the same  vector, just lagged one), and subtracting the vector all at once? e.g. `earlier_time <- c(USDJPY$TIME, NA) later_time <- c(NA, USDJPY$TIME) time_diff <- later_time - earlier_time`

Comment: What do you want your output to look like? This seems perfect for the `data.table` package. It should be able to process 1.9 million rows in seconds.

Comment: I want output to be indices of the last row in each time group (trading week). so, if those indices start like 113987, 245776, 342811, ... output should be a vector, list, or data.table

Answer (score 2):

I would think `data.table` should speed things up here quite a bit:

```
library(data.table) #1.9.5
setDT(data)
data[, DIFF := as.numeric(TIME-shift(TIME,n=1,type="lag"))]
```

Week number calc (increment with difference is greater than 12 hours)

```
data[, Week.num := cumsum(DIFF>12)]
```

Comment: am I supposed to be defining DIFF somehow? what about shift? I'm gonna play around with data.table and see how speed is improved but I run 

    library(data.table) #1.9.5
    setDT(USDJPY)
    USDJPY[, DIFF := as.numeric(TIME-shift(TIME,n=1,type="lag"))]

and get error

    data.table 1.9.4  For help type: ?data.table
    *** NB: by=.EACHI is now explicit. See README to restore previous     behaviour.
    Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "shift"
    In addition: Warning message:
    package ‘data.table’ was built under R version 3.1.3

Comment: You will have to download `data.table` version 1.9.5 first https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation

Comment: what is different between the github version and the cran version that will change the functionality for me?

Comment: It has the `shift` function that has been optimized for speed